# CSS align one div left and one right, switch them in each row?

Tags: html, css

Assume we only use CSS (not using any existing CSS libs), is this possible?

There are many divs (let's simply call them "rows").

In each div, there are one div called "image", one called "text".

The requirements are like:

We don't know the total width (in terms of pix), but we want the "image" to take 50% of space (width), and "text" to take 50% of width. And there will be a 20px white space in between them.

In odd rows (row 1, 3, 5, ...), we want the "image" to be on the left, "text" to be on the right.

In even rows (row 2, 4, 6, ...), we want the "image" to be on the right, "text" to be on the left.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

**Edit:**
Flexbox is not supported in older browsers like IE9. Works on all major browsers today. You might want to add [vendor prefixes](http://shouldiprefix.com/#flexbox) to serve slightly older browsers as well.

```css
.row{
  display:flex;
  height:30px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.row img, .row p{
   flex:1;
   
  }

.row p{
     margin:0;
     background:red;
  }
.row img{
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
  }

.row:nth-of-type(2n){
    flex-direction:row-reverse;
  }


.row:nth-of-type(2n) img{
    margin-left:20px;
  }

.row:nth-of-type(2n-1) p{
    margin-left:20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="rows">
<div class="row">
  <img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" />
  
  <p>Sample Text</p>
</div>  
  <div class="row">
  <img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" />
  
  <p>Sample Text</p>
</div>  
  <div class="row">
  <img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" />
  
  <p>Sample Text</p>
</div>  
  <div class="row">
  <img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" />
  
  <p>Sample Text</p>
</div>  
  <div class="row">
  <img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" />
  
  <p>Sample Text</p>
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox isn't supported in IE8/IE9, might be good to bring up.